# Why ends my docker-compose build in an error?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I new to docker and i want create a Spring-Boot / Angular app, that runs in one Container. I work on a windows 11 computer. I can run the Frontend with ng serve localy without any issues.

When i execute 'docker compose build' i get this error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2LVt.png)

This is my Dockerfile for the frontend. Most is Copy&Paste out of Tutorials and ChatGPT.

```
FROM node:16.14.0 AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
COPY ./package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json

RUN npm install

COPY . /app/

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=builder /app/dist /appnpm
```

This is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ../../xpenz/Frontend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: xpenz-frontend

  backend:
    build:
      context: ../../xpenz/Backend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: xpenz-backend
```

The Backend Dockerfile compiles without issue.

I had tried also some "solutions" from stackoverflow but these doesn't work for me.

Thanks for helping.

I had tried:

-RUN NODE_ENV=development npm i (insted of npm run build: this ends in the same error)

Comment: Your `docker build` fails on the 7th line `RUN npm run build`. The error you get there appears in the picture. Fix your build and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, unfortunally i didn't know how to fix the build on the 7th line "RUN npm run build". When i execute npm run build on VSC that works and the app is building.

Comment: The error is written right there, in your image, in the line starting with "0.783". If you need some help debugging that add the details to your question and maybe someone with some angular understanding will help you.

Comment: Seems like you don't have @angular/cli in your package.json

Comment: @EvgenyGurevich i had @angular/cli in the devDependencies and in the normal dependencies in the Angular App. Its the same Error

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install && \
    npm run build
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /appnpm
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).